# Set 1920x1080 resolution with Intel HD Graphics 3000

Tags: windows-7, resolution, intel-graphics

My NVIDIA Graphic Card is broken and therefore I'm using my Intel CPU as a graphic card now.

The graphic card of my CPU is Intel HD Graphics 3000, with Intel Core i7-2600K 3.40GHz CPU.

My problem is that I can not set the correct resolution. For my screen I need 1920 x 1080, but as you can see in the image below, in my operating system (Windows 7) I can select a screen resolution no greater than 1600 x 1200.

[image: screen resolution configuration printscreen]

When using NVIDIA graphic card I was able to set the proper resolution, 1920 x 1080.

I tried to contact Intel live chat support, but they told me that they no longer give support for my product. However they told me that with my hardware I should be able to reach 1920 x 1200, therefore my screen is within the range.

I have the last version of the driver.

Comment: Make sure your drivers are up to date. In device manager it should say Intel Graphics xxxxx. Not Basic Graphics Adapter. If it says the latter, make sure you get the right drivers installed.

Comment: _(Windows 7 is no longer supported, e.g. it's no longer receiving Windows Updates, so it's recommended to upgrade to Windows 10.)_ Update the integrated GPU drivers with the driver supplied via the OEM's support page, however, if that doesn't resolve the issue, it's likely that's the highest resolution supported by the integrated GPU _(it's too complex to explain in a comment, but if the integrated GPU does support the max resolution your screen supports, it's possible the OEM locked it to this max resolution)_.

Comment: @LPChip I have the last version of the driver.

Comment: @JW0914 see my prevois comment.

Comment: Go to `Device manager` and make sure that the `display adapter` Not to be `Microsoft Basic Graphics Adapter` as @LPChip said.

Comment: @C.F.G so, you are saying "make sure you are using the graphic card you think you are using". Ok, my question is: how can I select the graphic card I want to use?

Comment: @Boeing737 It's selected in the BIOS as to what GPU it uses, either Discrete [an actual GPU card] or integrated [GPU on the CPU]. In Device Manager, if it shows _Display Adapters_ →  _Microsoft Basic_, right-click → Update Driver →Choose Auto or Manual, however the best way would be to do what I previously mentioned... download the most recent driver from the OEM and install it → Reboot → If that doesn't show a higher resolution, then your integrated GPU doesn't support any resolution above what it's showing.

Comment: @Boeing737: Just a question: does all Intel core i7 2600 processors have same Intel-hd 3000 as gpu? I asked this because I want to buy a used PC  with this CPU soon.

Comment: @C.F.G I don't know